# PHP Blog system for MODx

Tags: php, blogs, modx

I run a site using the [MODx](http://modxcms.com/) Content Management System. What I'd like to do is set up a news feed on the front page, with a blog-style backend that supports the usual things (tags, categories, archives basically).

I've looked into the MODx plugins which provide this functionality (the deprecated NewsPublisher - which we use currently - and Ditto), but I don't like either of them that much. What I really want is something with an API, so that I can easily add news programmatically.

I've considered installing WordPress, however this seems like overkill given that we're just using it in a fairly basic way! I've also considered rolling my own, but before I do that I just wanted to check there wasn't something suitable out there already!

Does anyone have any suggestions for lightweight, highly customisable PHP blog / news frameworks with a decent API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **[Chyrp](http://chyrp.net/)** seems like an interestng option: clean, lightweight php/mysql/a dash of ajax (John Gruber [made note of it](http://daringfireball.net/linked/2008/february#wed-06-chyrp) earlier this year)

Comment: agreed. If to you, Wordpress seems like an overkill, Chyrp is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be worth your time to try out the Articles system on MODx. See [here](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/articles/articles.creating-a-blog) to get started.

I've used Wordpress a lot just as a blog engine and was shocked at how crude things seemed to be to me when I first dabbled in MODx. This Articles system is much closer to what I was expecting than the other MODx blogging tutorials I first came across. You get something much more like a working blog with very little hacking.

Of course... with the chunks, snippets, and templates in MODx... you should be able to make it do just about anything if you are happy with its basic stucture.

[Whoops: I just noticed how old this question is. Doh!]